# Vibration sensors for Virtual Reality

Tags: development, home-electronics, tracking-devices

I'am looking for very basic vibration sensors which I could use in a virtual reality environment. I have an HTC Vive and the idea would be to put some basic sensors (preferably wireless) all over the body and to make them vibrate on a specific part of the body when I get touched in the virtual env.

I don't need beautiful or sophisticated sensors but basic one which are wireless and can be controlled from a computer.

I'm in computer science field but have never worked in electronics field, does anyone knows such products?

Thanks